# Can I tweet mp4 files with tweepy?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I was just wondering if it was possible to tweet an mp4 file with tweepy (maybe using `api.update_with_media`). I've seen a post from a few years ago saying that it's not possible with the official tweepy, but I find it really hard to believe that there's no way to do it with the official tweepy. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_with_media` was deprecated as a Twitter API method about 5 years ago. This pre-dated the ability to upload GIFs and video MP4s. If you want to post media on Twitter via the API, you must find a library that supports the media upload endpoints (and chunked uploads). The process is

- upload the media file (chunked if necessary depending on size and format)
- retrieve a media ID string
- post a Tweet, and add the media ID to the Tweet.

Note that you can only post multiple images on a single Tweet; you can only post a single GIF or video file on a single Tweet, not multiple.

I do not believe the default Tweepy release supports this but I could be wrong, you’ll need to check the Tweepy documentation.

Do NOT use `update_with_media` - it’s very old and unsupported as an API path.

Also worth being aware that tweepy itself is a third party library - that we at Twitter LOVE - but this is not officially supported.

Comment: ```update_with_media``` seems to allow me to upload both images AND gifs, just not videos. Is there a modified version of the original tweepy library that supports media uploads you could please direct me to? Tweepy is so simple and straightforward and I'd hate to have to switch to a completely different library.

Comment: Again, I’m not able to provide you with that link because Twitter does not maintain Tweepy, but we love the Tweepy contributors. Please check with them.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information above! I'll probably use something like the imgur api to upload the video, then tweet the link, as Tweepy is too good to leave behind.